# relative path is not working in internet explorer on zend modular structure

Tags: zend-framework

I am using modular structure in Zend and having separate layout, router, configuration in every module folder.

in my module/admin/layout.phtml file when i add the url

```
<a href="/mypage/index">test</a>
```

on Firefox it goes to http://zendbase.local/mypage/index which is correct path. 
but on internet explorer it goes to http:///mypage/index which is incorrect path

why is it behaving like this in IE. where I am doing wrong?
I don't know why IE misses the Server Name.

Comment: can you put the source code of that link from the web browser?

Comment: it is hosted on localhost(http://zendbase.local/mypage/index ) and link source is already in my question. <a href="/mypage/index">test</a>

Comment: That's a local url, not a public one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is

I removed the baseUrl(); ?>" /> from layout.phtml
and added following line in application.ini
resources.frontController.baseUrl = ""

Answer (score 0):

I think its an IE (proxy problem) i have no IE on OSx but there must be a setting to skip proxy for localhost.

I bet http://127.0.0.1/ will work :-)